# Actionscript3 parsing json with an object

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I have a flash app where in a function I have to parse a json passed like an object by some external API that I can't change.

my json look like this:

```
 {
    "prodotti": [
        {
            "titolo": "test",
            "marca": "",
            "modello": "",
            "cilindrata": "",
            "potenza": "",
            "alimentazione": "",
            "images": {
                "img": [
                    {
                        "thumb": "admin/uploads/img_usato/small/qekabw95L5WH1ALf6.jpg",
                        "big": "admin/uploads/img_usato/big/qekabw95L5WH1ALf6.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "thumb": "admin/uploads/img_usato/small/default.jpg",
                        "big": "admin/uploads/img_usato/big/default.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "titolo": "Motore Volvo TAMD 74 C",
            "marca": "VOLVO PENTA",
            "modello": "TAMD 74 C",
            "cilindrata": "7.283 cm3",
            "potenza": "331 kW a 2600 rpm",
            "alimentazione": "Gasolio",
            "images": {
                "img": [
                    {
                        "thumb": "admin/uploads/img_usato/small/PmQwN4t4yp7P1YCWa.jpg",
                        "big": "admin/uploads/img_usato/big/PmQwN4t4yp7P1YCWa.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "thumb": "admin/uploads/img_usato/small/BWkjTGcy3pDM2LKRs.jpg",
                        "big": "admin/uploads/img_usato/big/BWkjTGcy3pDM2LKRs.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to parse the images inside the object.
The API send me an object not astring or json and I have this function now:

```
function changeData (prodotto:Object) {
    img_container.graphics.clear ();

        //here I want to enter and take thumb and big of images!!!
    for (var index in prodotto.images.img) {
        //trace('index: ' + index);
        //trace("thumb: " + index.thumb + ' big: ' + index.big);
    }

        descrizione.htmlText = prodotto.testo_html;
        titolo.text = prodotto.titolo;
        alimentazione.text = prodotto.alimentazione;
        potenza.text = prodotto.potenza;
        cilindrata.text = prodotto.cilindrata;
        modello.text = prodotto.modello;
        marca.text = prodotto.marca;

}
```

The function works fine but not for the for loop where I try to take the bug and thumb of my json how can I retrieve this information in this object?

Thanks

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, check http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You have trailing commas that make it invalid. If that really is what you are getting from the API and you cannot change it, I suggest showing whoever made it this thread. It is clearly invalid.

Comment: I have update my json, I have wrong to copy it, but the problem is the  same it wasn't that @Ronnie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with how you are setting up the call back but since you didn't show code for the api we can't fix that, plus you stated you have no control over it.
No matter what the issue is it just does not seem correct.

I put together a function that will get all the thumbs and bigs.
You did not state otherwise.

```
function changeData (prodotto:Object) {
    for each(var item in prodotto.prodotti){
        trace('')
        //trace(prodotto.testo_html);
        trace(item.titolo);
        trace(item.alimentazione);
        trace(item.potenza);
        trace(item.cilindrata);
        trace(item.modello);
        trace(item.marca);
        for each( var imgs in item.images.img) {
            trace('thumb',imgs.thumb)
            trace('big',imgs.big)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need a cycle because i can get  the other attributes like "modello" but not attributes inside image. I need a cycle only for images. Your cycle is out of this function. Thanks

Comment: What is a cycle???  This function will trace everything in your json object. You stated you wanted the "big" and "thumb" This function gives you all the "big" and "thumb" Nobody can answer your question the way you want unless you explain what you want.

Comment: sorry cycle means loop, The loop is outside the function, because I can take other attributes but not thumb and big

Comment: You said this is the jSon that is getting passed into the function. If that is so then what happens outside of the function is not relevant. If you are modifying that jSon Object before passing it into the function then you need to show what exactly you are passing into the fucntion

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a JSON parser. Use the one from this link: https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

**1:** Add the `com` folder to your project directory **or** add it to your default class path.

**2:** Adapt this code to your liking. I am not sure how you're getting a literal object from the API. It really should just be a string unless you're using some sort of AMF. Regardless...

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.*;
var data:String = '{"prodotti":[{"titolo":"test","marca":"","modello":"","cilindrata":"","potenza":"","alimentazione":"","images":{"img":[{"thumb":"admin/uploads/img_usato/small/qekabw95L5WH1ALf6.jpg","big":"admin/uploads/img_usato/big/qekabw95L5WH1ALf6.jpg"},{"thumb":"admin/uploads/img_usato/small/default.jpg","big":"admin/uploads/img_usato/big/default.jpg"}]}},{"titolo":"Motore Volvo TAMD 74 C","marca":"VOLVO PENTA","modello":"TAMD 74 C","cilindrata":"7.283 cm3","potenza":"331 kW a 2600 rpm","alimentazione":"Gasolio","images":{"img":[{"thumb":"admin/uploads/img_usato/small/PmQwN4t4yp7P1YCWa.jpg","big":"admin/uploads/img_usato/big/PmQwN4t4yp7P1YCWa.jpg"},{"thumb":"admin/uploads/img_usato/small/BWkjTGcy3pDM2LKRs.jpg","big":"admin/uploads/img_usato/big/BWkjTGcy3pDM2LKRs.jpg"}]}}]}';

function changeData(data)
{
    img_container.graphics.clear();
    var obj = JSON.decode(data);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < obj.prodotti.length; i++)
    {
        for (var k in obj.prodotti[i].images.img)
        {
            trace("Thumb:",obj.prodotti[i].images.img[k].thumb);
            trace("Big:",obj.prodotti[i].images.img[k].big);
        }
        descrizione.htmlText    = obj.prodotti[i].testo_html;
        titolo.text             = obj.prodotti[i].titolo;
        alimentazione.text      = obj.prodotti[i].alimentazione;
        potenza.text            = obj.prodotti[i].potenza;
        cilindrata.text         = obj.prodotti[i].cilindrata;
        modello.text            = obj.prodotti[i].modello;
        marca.text              = obj.prodotti[i].marca;
    }
}
changeData(data);
```

Comment: I have specified that the argument is passed by external API that I can' modify, I have to use the variable of type Object for this, if I could change I know thatyour way is the best, but not in my case because I have an Object

Comment: Well if it is already object, then just try using my loop. All the `JSON.decode()` does is convert that string into an object.

Comment: but the part of the other attributes it was ok, I don't need the loop fot hhose attributes but only for the images, the rest of the function is ok

Comment: Welp, it's worth a shot. My loop should work, take it or leave it